# tkinter checkbutton to alter function value

Tags: python, tkinter

As a personal project I am attempting to create a program to calculate the calories burnt during treadmill running. The basic program works, but I would like the user to be able to select the measurement units they prefer e.g. lbs or kg. for this I thought that a check button would be most appropriate, but I really can't figure out how to make the selected checkbutton alter the function. so if the user selected 'lbs' i would then need the function to divide the value by roughly 2.2 to convert it into KG. I've read some of the other questions must I just can't seem to connect the dots. Any help would be much appreciated :). I have printed my code out below.

```
from tkinter import *

#function def calculate():  mass = float(mass1.get())   gradient_q = float(gradient1.get())     gradient = gradient_q/100   minutes = float(minutes1.get())     seconds = float(seconds1.get())     speed = float(speed1.get())     vo2 = 3.5 + (0.2 * (speed * 26.82))+(gradient * (speed * 26.82) * 0.9)  mets = vo2 / 3.5    cal_m = (vo2 * mass)/1000 *
5.05    total_cal = ((seconds/60) + minutes) * cal_m    tcal = Label(window, text='total calories burned:%.2f' % total_cal).grid(row=8,column=1)    return


window = Tk() window.title('Calorie Calculator') window.geometry('400x600')

title=Label(window,text='Treadmill Calorie Counter', font='bold').grid(columnspan=4) title=Label(window,text='').grid(columnspan=2)

mass1 = StringVar() gradient1 = StringVar() minutes1 = StringVar() seconds1 = StringVar() speed1 = StringVar()

var=StringVar()

mass=Label(window,text='Mass').grid(row=2,column=0) mass_e=Entry(window, textvariable=mass1).grid(row=2,column=1) c = Checkbutton (window, text='kg').grid(row=2,column=2) c = Checkbutton (window, text='lbs').grid(row=2, column=3)

gradient=Label(window,text='Gradient').grid(row=3,column=0) gradient_e=Entry(window, textvariable=gradient1).grid(row=3,column=1)

minutes=Label(window,text='Minutes').grid(row=4,column=0) minutes_e=Entry(window, textvariable=minutes1).grid(row=4,column=1)

seconds=Label(window,text='Seconds').grid(row=5,column=0) seconds_e=Entry(window, textvariable=seconds1).grid(row=5,column=1)

speed=Label(window,text='Speed').grid(row=6,column=0) speed_e=Entry(window, textvariable=speed1).grid(row=6,column=1)

c = Checkbutton (window, text='kph',variable=var).grid(row=6,column=2) c = Checkbutton (window, text='mph').grid(row=6, column=3)

calculate = Button(window, text='Calculate',command=calculate).grid(row=7,column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is perhaps the least readable code listing I have seen for a long time. Don't worry, help is coming!

Comment: Oh no lol! Sorry about that.

Comment: It's still unreadable. There seems to be a lot of missing newlines.

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code so now it will check wich checkbutton is active.

I also put in a small function that will make sure only one checkbutton is selected at a time. I alsways had a problem with user that selected both options.

Here is the updated Code:

```
from tkinter import *

def calculate():

   #this will check which checkbutton is active
   if cbSpeed[0].get() == 1:
        print "kph"
   else:
        print "mph"

   if cbUnit[0].get() == 1:
        print "kg"
   else:
        print "lbs"

   mass = float(mass1.get()) 
   gradient_q = float(gradient1.get()) 
   gradient = gradient_q/100 
   minutes = float(minutes1.get()) 
   seconds = float(seconds1.get()) 
   speed = float(speed1.get()) 
   vo2 = 3.5 + (0.2 * (speed * 26.82))+(gradient * (speed * 26.82) * 0.9) 
   mets = vo2 / 3.5 
   cal_m = (vo2 * mass)/1000 * 5.05 
   total_cal = ((seconds/60) + minutes) * cal_m 
   tcal = Label(window, text='total calories burned:%.2f' % total_cal).grid(row=8,column=1) 

def changeCB(buttons,no):
#This function will make sure only one checkbutton is selected at a time

    for i in range(0,len(buttons)):

        if i <> no:

            buttons[i].set(0)


window = Tk() 
window.title('Calorie Calculator') 
window.geometry('400x600')

title=Label(window,text='Treadmill Calorie Counter', font='bold').grid(columnspan=4) 
title=Label(window,text='').grid(columnspan=2)

mass1 = StringVar() 
gradient1 = StringVar() 
minutes1 = StringVar() 
seconds1 = StringVar() 
speed1 = StringVar()

var=StringVar()

mass=Label(window,text='Mass').grid(row=2,column=0) 
mass_e=Entry(window, textvariable=mass1).grid(row=2,column=1) 

#the following will create an array with 2 entrys. One entry per checkbutton
cbUnit = []
for i in range(0,2):
    cbUnit.append(0)
    cbUnit[i] = IntVar()

#this will set the first checkbutton as default
cbUnit[0].set(1)

c = Checkbutton (window, text='kg',variable=cbUnit[0],command = lambda: changeCB(cbUnit,0)).grid(row=2,column=2) 
c = Checkbutton (window, text='lbs',variable=cbUnit[1],command = lambda: changeCB(cbUnit,1)).grid(row=2, column=3)

gradient=Label(window,text='Gradient').grid(row=3,column=0) 
gradient_e=Entry(window, textvariable=gradient1).grid(row=3,column=1)

minutes=Label(window,text='Minutes').grid(row=4,column=0) 
minutes_e=Entry(window, textvariable=minutes1).grid(row=4,column=1)

seconds=Label(window,text='Seconds').grid(row=5,column=0) 
seconds_e=Entry(window, textvariable=seconds1).grid(row=5,column=1)

speed=Label(window,text='Speed').grid(row=6,column=0) 
speed_e=Entry(window, textvariable=speed1).grid(row=6,column=1)

#sames as with units
cbSpeed = []
for i in range(0,2):
    cbSpeed.append(0)
    cbSpeed[i] = IntVar()

cbSpeed[0].set(1)
c = Checkbutton (window, text='kph',variable=cbSpeed[0],command = lambda: changeCB(cbSpeed,0)).grid(row=6,column=2) 
c = Checkbutton (window, text='mph',variable=cbSpeed[1],command = lambda: changeCB(cbSpeed,1)).grid(row=6, column=3)


calculate = Button(window, text='Calculate',command=calculate).grid(row=7,column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Fist of all thank you very much for taking the time to help me this! I copied the code and tried to run it but I get this error message "File "Untitled 13.py", line 7
    print 'kph'
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax" . Not sure how to correct it as lots of the coding you have used is completely new to me.

Comment: Ah it needed brackets :). I'm working in python 3. but now I got another error lol:   File "Untitled 13.py", line 33
    if i <> no:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: To solve the problem of "only one checkbutton checked at a time", the solution is to use radiobuttons. Radiobuttons exist precisely to solve this problem -- provide a way to pick only one of several choices.

Comment: @BryanOakley ok thanks, but how would I make these radio buttons connect with my function? for e.g. multiplying the speed by 0.621371 to convert kph to mph.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7. I never used 3.0 so im not sure what the correct syntex would be but that shouldnt be to hard to google.

Comment: @Pendragon02 Ok no worries, thanks for your help though, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, your checkbuttons or radiobuttons are associated with a variable, and whenever you do your calculations you use the value of that variable. Plus, the buttons can call a function when they are clicked which gives you the opportunity to re-calculate your results whenever a button is selected.

If you are presenting the user with an exclusive choice (lbs or kg), the proper widget to use is a Radiobutton rather than a Checkbutton. You tie the radiobuttons together by having them share a variable. The variable will only ever have the value of the selected button.

The code in your question is nearly impossible to read, so here's a generic example:

```
def calculate():
    units = weightUnits.get()
    if units == "lbs":
        ...
    else:
        ...

weightUnits = StringVar(value="lbs")
lbsChoice = Radiobutton(..., text="lbs", value="lbs", 
                        variable=weightUnits, command=calculate)
lbsChoice = Radiobutton(..., text="kg", value="kg", 
                        variable=weightUnits, command=calculate)
```